# Insert Text between "List of XXX" Heading and Actual Listing

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, minted

I would like to insert a small paragraph of text between the "List of Figures" heading and the actual list of figures, and also between "List of Listings" and the actual list of listings. I am using the `listing` environment provided by `minted`.

What's the best and easiest way to do this?

Edit: A picture in case I wasn't clear enough:

[image]

Edit2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{listing}
\caption{A listing}
\label{fig:listing}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you provided a "skeleton document" (MWE) to show what to work from.

Comment: It's very important that you specify the class you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can patch the `\@starttoc` command so that it inserts something that you've specified in advance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\@starttoc{\csname #1@prolog\endcsname}{}{}
\newcommand{\listprolog}[2]{\global\@namedef{#1@prolog}{#2\par\bigskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listprolog{lof}{This is what I want to appear as a prolog to the list of figures.

It even has two paragraphs.}

\listprolog{lol}{This is what I want to appear as a prolog to the list of listings}

\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{A figure}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{listing}
\caption{A listing}
\label{fig:listing}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\listprolog` is the list file extension

- `lot` for the list of tables
- `lof` for the list of figures
- `lol` for the list of listings

The second argument is the prolog text.

[image]